What happens when battery polarity flipped over my MOSFETs?
I have the following high side switch circuit in a device.
By mistake, the 3.6V LTC battery was connected in the reverse polarity (it was connected as drawn in the figure, but the circuit is designed for the positive pole to be upwards and GND downwards). The MCU with the GPIOs was unpowered.
What do you think happens and why?


Depends, what's the common between this and whatever drives GPIO1 and GPIO2?

Thanks. As i wrote, it was unpowered. The GND of the MCU was connected to + of the battery (when it was inserted in the wrong direction) and VDD of the MCu was connected to the output of an LDO. The LDO didn't run as it was fed with -3.6V instead of +3.6V, so all other circuitry was cut off.

I thought about the GPIOs as high z but was more wondering about the FETs. The lower one will conduct through the body diode, but what about the upper one?

You've almost created a reverse polarity circuit with the P MOSFET getting pulled high upon polarity switch. The 100k resistor will conduct however, but it's such a tiny current that nothing should take damage.

Unpowered isn't enough to answer the question. Is bottom MOSFET source connected to same ground as your MCU? Ideally, please show with the full schematic.

What will happen is that any load (not shown) will always be powered by the reverse voltage. The body diode in the TSM MOSFET will always be forward-biased, so current will flow freely from the battery to the load.
The high-side switch (shown in your diagram) will not be damaged. And the GPIO1 line will be protected by the high resistance of the 100 k resistor. So, nothing bad will happen. But, if there is a load connected to your circuit (not shown) it will be powered in the reverse direction and it will probably be damaged.
